# Chrome Console Log Can't see AJAX post/get requests/response

Tags: google-chrome, console

I don't know if its from one of Chromes recent updates I don't know if its an option I managed to turn off unknowingly. But either way sometime in the Past couple of days my Console Log on Chrome stopped showing post/get requests so I can see whats going on as far as whats being posted and what the response is being sent back, I know it wasn't exactly like firebug on firefox but similar none the less.

If firebug on chrome didn't get in my way more than it was helpful I would use it, but its to intrusive to my needs in chrome as I can't scroll all the way down an all else. And everytime I refresh the page I lose my data I am trying to track for bugs.

So Question is, is there a means of turning this back on? The ability to see the POST/GET requests/responses. I know I can turn on "Log XMLHttpRequests" but that only shows me what functions are being fired off, and not the actual posted data or response.

Comment: Not sure about how to turn this on, but http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/ will do this and it bypasses chrome.

Comment: Now, that may be helpful for somethings, but 2 problems I have with it at the moment, is one thats going to output more information that I need from all streams open at the time (from the sound of it). Two I am also on a Mac :-)

Comment: You can filter the information & well that's what you get for using a mac :P

Comment: hahah, good to know, when Im on my windows machine I'll keep this app in mind.

Comment: I've got the same problem too, since several weeks some XHR requests are not showed in the Network log, reason unknow :/

Answer (score 11):

Open the console, then check "Preserve Log".

If you want to see AJAX post/get requests/response do the following:

1. Open the console
2. Right-click into the console log stream
3. Check or select "Log XMLHttpRequests"

[image: Here is an image of what im talking about]

Comment: thank you! this is exactly what I have been looking for!

Answer (score 4):

right click on console area, select "Preserve Log Upon Navigation" then refresh the page ( or do any get/post operation) the GET/POST logs will be visible.

alternately, the "Network" tab is also useful to check the GET/POST events.

make sure you don't miss anything like this - [Chrome: console.log, console.debug are not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18760213/chrome-console-log-console-debug-are-not-working)