# Chrome: console.log, console.debug are not working

Tags: google-chrome, console

Console.log and debug not printing, only return undefined. Why it can be?
I've tried to re-install chrome, but it doesn't help.

Here is screenshot from chrome's main page, so functions are not redefined in some code
[image: console.log doesn't work]

Comment: Make sure you have some value typed in the filter field.

Comment: For anyone doing web development with Flask:  I ran into this same issue -- adding console.log statements to my Javascript, and nothing was displaying in the console.  Problem turned out to be due to browser caching... it wasn't seeing my added log statements.  Solution is a hard refresh (CTRL+F5 instead of F5 on Windows).  Hope that helps someone else with the same issue!

Comment: i accidently had some text in the filter field

Comment: 2021 and still the same problem. So every time I want to console.log something I need to press Ctrl+F5.

Comment: **Sometimes the website overrides the default (window.) console.log** :)

Answer (score 410, accepted):

Click “Default levels” and make sure that "Verbose" is checked. By default it is only set to show Errors and Warnings

I came here with the same problem :/

Comment: Thanks...I just thought the new version chrome does not work well !

Comment: @NikhilPatil not stupid at all. That's just a terrible default setting.

Comment: Me too feeling stupid.I even reported an issue, that chrome developer tool is not working.

Comment: also with newer versions: if javascript is disabled, console just goes blank after enter. won't tell you what the problem is. enabling javascript on that site does enable the console again.

Comment: Strange, cause i have encounter a situation where inside a script tag it's not working.. and inside a js file it works.. very strange xD

Comment: With all those settings correct, I updated Chrome from v52 to v53 in mac and it started working . version problem for me !

Comment: Just a note for later versions of Chrome: it looks like it's a dropdown at the top now, and you'll want to change it to "Verbose" to see everything.

Comment: how is this a thing?!

Comment: Nice. I agree with @HashRocketSyntax - How is this a thing?  This will be very helpful in the future...

Comment: "Default levels" greyed out, cannot click, i.e. cannot change ...

Figured it out: There's a message tree in the left sidebar, one of the items is "info"!

Comment: and where is deafult levels

Comment: This solved my slightly different error: I had accidentally typed something into the "Filter" box (next to the levels dropdown) the day before.

Comment: i have checked all levels still not working ?

Answer (score 57):

For completeness: In the current version of chrome, the setting is no longer at the bottom but can be found when clicking the "Filter" icon at the top of the console tab (second icon from the left)

Answer (score 46):

As of today, the user interface (UI) of developer tools in Google Chrome has changed. It has changed in terms of the place in UI where we select log level of the logs being shown in the console. There is a **Level** drop-down to the right of **Filter** input box. Supported values in the drop-down are:

- Verbose
- Info
- Warnings
- Errors

The default selection in the drop-down is **Info** (Refer screenshot).

[image]

Any log statement whose severity is equal or higher than the *selected* log-level then only, it will get displayed in the Console tab e.g. if selected log level is **Info** then any log statement having log-level **Info**, **Warning** or **Error** will get displayed in the Console tab.

When I changed it to **Verbose** then log statements corresponding to `console.debug` and `console.log` started showing-up in the Console tab. Till the time **Info** level was selected, log statements were not getting displayed.

Answer (score 34):

Make sure that the "Filter" input is left blank and nothing is written intentionally or by mistake. That was it in my case :P

[image]

Comment: It remembers this across sessions -tripped me up as well.

Comment: THIS IS IT! Thank you

Comment: OPMG I do this all the time! I wish it was more obvious.  THANK YOU

Answer (score 29):

Same issue, but I just cleared my settings. I went into Settings > Preferences and Clicked [Restore defaults and reload]. Just remember what your settings were.

[image]

Comment: I spent days on debugging this issue, and this solution worked like magic!

Comment: I used this but I ticked disable cache under Network and that then worked

Comment: I spent 3-4 hours trying to work out why Next.js wasn't running any code on the client side while working on a technical assignment for a new job, turns out this was all that was wrong. I have no idea why it was broken but the SO post may have saved my chances of getting an amazing job

Comment: If you can't find these settings, press F1 inside the dev tools.

Answer (score 13):

I experienced the same problem. The solution for me was to disable Firebug because Firebug was intercepting the logs in the background resulting in no logs being shown in the Chrome console.

Answer (score 12):

There could also be some filters applied to the console. Remove them.

Answer (score 7):

Sometimes the simplest things trip us up...

Type `console.log` in the console and check what function gets returned. If you see `ƒ log() { [native code] }` then it's something else. If you see `ƒ (){}` then somewhere down the line the native console.log function was changed.

Was working on a client's site today and that was the issue. If that's the case, you can either manually restore the console.log function or use console.dir() or console.warn() instead.

If you see `ƒ (){}` then there is a possibility that sometime console stops working due to some functionality you have added in your javascript. so first close all tabs restart chrome and in a new tab just typ1 `console.log('hi');` if it prints that then it confirms that the problem is there in your script code. if not then restore the cosole.log.

To restore the console in new tab go to console and type `delete window.console` it will return `true` after that restart the chrome and you are good to go.

Comment: in my case it was 3rd-side ad script, it is blocking console, then trying to load ad, then restoring console, but ad was blocked by CORS, and no console.log restoration occured

Answer (score 7):

Another tip, why `console.log` doesn't works is that the **Filter search field must be empty.**

[image]

Answer (score 6):

In my case was webpack having the UglifyPlugin running with `drop_console: true` set

Comment: I have the same problem. uglify is removing the logging. Thank you

Comment: Is it possible to restore it once a site script drops it like that?

Answer (score 6):

As of July 2020 the Chrome UI has changed once again and the logging level dropdown doesn't seem to do anything now.

Instead, there's a new pane to the left of the main console pane, which may have got unintentionally set to one of the restrictive logging levels:

[image]

Select the top category (messages) to reveal all the logging:

[image]

**EDIT: EVEN THEN Chrome seems to add things to the Filter box**, which again loses some logging, so you must CLEAR THE FILTER BOX TOO!

(Filter box is at the top of both my pics above, under "Network conditions"; you can see that it has some contents about "urlwebpack" which I didn't put there!)

Comment: _THE_ new answer. It shouldn't be this hard ಠಿ_ಠ

Answer (score 5):

I'm working on a site where some JS (or other) code is preventing `console.log` from working (`console.log` is probably overwritten). You can test this by checking if `console.log` works on a different page (like this one).

I don't have time to investigate further right now so used `alert("something is: "+something)` to get the info I wanted from a snippet I needed to run.

Comment: https://forum.xda-developers.com is an example of a prominent site that disables `console.log`.

Answer (score 5):

Click “**Default levels**” right next to filter and do make sure that "**Info**" is checked.

Please see screenshot:

[image]

Comment: This just duplicates [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18853868/3303195) with a screenshot. You could make a better contribution by suggesting an edit to the currently accepted answer to include your screenshot.

Answer (score 4):

If you are seeing(3 messages are hidden by filters. Show all messages.) then click on show all message link in Chrome dev tool console.

Because if this option enabled by mistake the `console.log("")` message will show but this will in in hidden state.

Answer (score 4):

In my case preserve logs do the trick. I did everything to show the logs, but it goes away. I checked it and it works,

[image]

Answer (score 3):

In my case it was just an old cached Javascript file. After clearing the cache I saw my logs.

Answer (score 3):

Selecting verbose fixed it for me[image: Verbose]

Answer (score 3):

In my case, i was not able to see logs because there is some text in Filter field, which caused results of console.log to disappear. Once we clear text in Filter field, it should show.

Comment: Thanks - fixed it for me!

Answer (score 2):

see if something show on the filter box in console ,it means something override your script 
clear the filter box and check again. i my case this is the issue.

Answer (score 1):

## React Dev Tools Extension Causing the Issue

If you have [React Developer Tools](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/react-developer-tools/fmkadmapgofadopljbjfkapdkoienihi) **chrome** extension installed, unistalling it fixed my issue. Obviously this might be a difficult trade off.

I never used them so deleting them solved it in my case.

[image]

Comment: Installed for... VSCode? Node Package Manager? Something else?

Comment: @TekuConcept as chrome extension.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me. In the  console section, go to the settings on top right. There select preserve log and Log XMLHttpsRequests.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the filter box is empty

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the solution was for me to click on "Top" and select debuggerWorker.aca... localhost:8081

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your webpack configuration file does not include any statement to drop console logs. (e.g drop_console: true).

If it does, change that statement and restart your project. (e.g. npm run start) Recompiling instead of restarting would have no effect since webpack configurations are only read in the start.