# Chrome is blocking console.log messages for a specific domain

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, console.log

The title pretty much says it all. I uploaded this HTML file to 2 domains:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
console.log('test');
alert('test');
</script>
```

On both domains, I get the alert that pops up. But on 1 domain, the console message is never logged. I tried on different computers.

I did this test because as I was working I noticed my messages were no longer coming in. After trying every setting in Chrome, I finally uninstalled Chrome and re-installed but the problem persisted. Finally, I changed computers and the problem persists on this computer.

I can't imagine what the problem is. It can't be anything in HTML file (as the file is as simple as it gets) and I tried on 2 systems soooo... is my domain somehow blocked somewhere? Has anyone ever heard of an issue like this?

Comment: There isn't any other code, or an extension, overwriting `console.log`, is there?

Comment: The HTML file contains the above code only...

Comment: But maybe there's an extension?

Comment: If it were an extension it would affect both domains, unless the extension is targeting a specific one. And it would have had to of been installed on both of the different systems he tested it on.

Comment: @Kevin OP never said they were the same website

Comment: @KevinB, yes exactly. It's a really weird problem and I was positive it was just a bug. But to happen on 2 computers is weird.

Comment: It's 2 websites - 1 is working as expected. The other site messages are not showing from 2 different computers

Comment: Are they publicly accessible? maybe we can help you debug

Comment: If you go to these websites, and open the javascript console, and type `console` do you get a the same object in both? As others have mentioned, it sounds like your `console` object or `console.log` function are being overridden by an external script or extension.

Comment: Is the one that isn't working being proxied through something like cloudflare, or anything else that may be modifying the src returned to the client? have you inspected using View Source?

Comment: The one that isn't working is on a local server running MAMP. The one that is working is running off Unix server. But the 2nd was just a test, it seems console is working just not on this specific domain running off my local server.

Comment: As a test, I just made the domain point to a remote server (instead of my local server), uploaded the same script, and it worked. I then updated my hosts file so it points back to my local and boom, it's working. It seems this somehow refreshed something. However, this only worked on 1 computer. I tried the trick on the first computer and still not working... super weird.

Comment: Having the same problem and it's driving my crazy! The console is not working only for my localhost:8081. There are no filters, I've tried a clean Chrome profile, nothing works. I can type anything on the console, it won't work. If I open any other website, type something, open my localhost:8081 without closing the console and type somthing, it still won't work. Then I change between "Elements" and "Console" and then I can read what I've entered. For now, I'm using Chrome Canary ... :(

Comment: After weeks of suffering, I've found that Chrome 39.0.2171.95 console, for some reason, stops working when you load files with % inside parameters. I had `<script data-main="js/main" src="js/require.js?version=%VERSION%" type="text/javascript"></script>` to replace `%VERSION%` later during build and had to change it to something else. I hope it helps somebody!

Answer (score 0):

**Is this happening?**

Click “All” on the bottom toolbar. Currently it is showing errors only.

[Similar Question, this may help you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18760213/chrome-console-log-console-debug-are-not-working)

Comment: Messages are set to all in both tests. No other filtering or specific settings.