# console.log() in chrome is not working properly

Tags: javascript

I am trying to console.log in chrome. just basic stuff.this is my html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>hello</h1>
    <button onClick="clickme()">click</button>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="index.js"></script> 
</body>
</html>
```

now my js file include

```
var name="abc";
console.log("hello " + name);
 clickme=()=>{
   document.body.style.backgroundColor="red";

   alert(name);
     console.log("hello " + name);

}
```

The alerts work. The background image gets change on button click but the `console.log` is not working. It works using node js and when used in edge browser.
Is there something missing.

Comment: does it print after you dismiss the alert box? the alert will stop execution.

Comment: Both of the `console.log` are not working?

Comment: no it doesnot. even if i have only console.log("hello") in whole of my  js file ,it doesnot work. another wired thing is in the chrome console if i type the console.log("whatever") it says undefined.

Comment: From the code you have posted above, both of your `console.log()` statements work correctly. Your problem lies elsewhere. Please ensure you have provided a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the problem.

Comment: @SaifUrRahman yes both of them do not work. its happening recently. i never such issue before.

Comment: html element doesn't have `onClick` prop, right is `onclick`

Comment: It works fine for me.
You probably should check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18853868) thread.

Comment: The code works on Chrome 67.

Comment: Have you disabled you chrome console by any chance ? Eg. by redefining the `log` function, like `console.log = function() {}`?

Comment: now out of nowhere the code is working. i did not change a single line of code.  its so frustrating..sorry guys

Comment: @amritchhetri - you're not alone :p Chrome failed the first time for me too - I thought I must've made a typo when checking your code - it's probably the government spying on us :p

Comment: Had you written something (perhaps accidentally) in the `filter` field ?

Comment: @collapsar u got me. i dont know how or when but there was letter "c" in the filter field. and it was giving all sort of issues .

Comment: `<button type="button" onclick="clickme()">click</button>`

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have `Info` checked in your `Default-levels` dropdown settings:
[image]

`console.log()` always returns `undefined` (correct me if I am wrong), but prints the value passed to it in the console.

Comment: its enabled..when u are executing console.log(name) you are getting abc in return. mine is only returning undefined

Comment: Is the preserve log option checked? Make sure the page is not getting refreshed.

Comment: why would the page be refreshed?

Comment: The browser seems to be broken. In case it is refreshing the page on a button click. Just to be sure.

Comment: Does `console.log` returns `ƒ log() { [native code] }`?

Comment: @SaifUrRahman  i dont know how or when but there was letter "c" written in the filter field in the chrome dev tool and it was giving all sort of issues .

Comment: Lol. You were filtering out the results.

Answer (score 0):

https://codesandbox.io/s/p9zjw8lxrm

Here I have an alert and console.log. You can see alert is running, but console.log does not get to run until you close the alert.

```
var name = "abc";
console.log("hello " + name);

document.getElementById("btn").onclick = function() {
  clickme();
};

const clickme = () => {
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = "red";

  alert(name);
  console.log("hello " + name);
};
```

When you first run the problem, you should see an alert, then after would be the console.log

When you load up the page,

First you get `hello abc`

Then Alert box, you click yes

Then `hello abc`

Comment: The code works on Chrome 67. Alert interrupts script execution until the dialog is acknowledged, this is the standard behavior.

Comment: is working properly in chrome. so the issue is no chrome or the console.log

Comment: @armrit i am running it on Chrome.

Comment: @leogoesger when you execute console.log("abc") in chrome dev tool are you getting abc or undefined.

Comment: @JaromandaX sorry, I corrected it. The problem was with my onClick. But I edited the code and fixed it. ty

Comment: @amritchhetri I edit the answer, you first get `hello abc`, then `alert`, then `hello abc`