# Javascript console warn function not working?

Tags: javascript, console

Using the console.log(), error() and warn() a lot but for some reason warn() no longer works. Chrome seems to still work but FireFox and Brave both don't output anything to the console. I use it a lot in the dev tools for testing snippits and it's helpful to call out things while testing where an error is too stong a notice. All the other console functions seem to work it's just warn().

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en-us">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>console test</title>
    <meta name="description" content="console test">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>

<body>
    <script>
        console.log('ddd');
        console.warn('ddd');
        console.error('ddd');
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

maybe a setting in the current updates that i'm missing but can't seem to find an answer. Could create my own override but wondering if anyone else has seen why the native function doesn't work. It does return 'undefined' like the other functions when in the dev tools.

Comment: the code you shared works correctly as expected.. using both chrome and firefox latest versions. There's a chance you have an addon maybe overriding those functions or maybe your system is corrupted somehow

Comment: Make sure you’re not filtering any console messages in the console settings.

Comment: There are some hints here if you may need to change your settings...
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18760213/chrome-console-log-console-debug-are-not-working

Comment: Do you have the [Warnings console filter](//i.stack.imgur.com/gO5jQ.png) enabled?

Comment: Thank you Sebastian, yes someone clicked off the warnings filter and couldn't see it was off. Thank you too Diego for the link.